# igraph delete_edges is behaving strangely

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to delete an edge from a graph.

I ran the following code

```
library(igraph)

A <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
dim(A) <- c(5,5)
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(t(A), mode = c("directed")) 

g1 <- delete_edges(g1, c(1,2))
g1 <- simplify(g1)

coords <- c(0.0, 0.951056, 0.587785, -0.587785, -0.951056,
            1, 0.309017, -0.809017,-0.809017,  0.309017)
dim(coords) <- c(5,2)

plot(g1, 
     vertex.color=c(rgb(0,.5,.7), 
                    rgb(.15,.6,0), 
                    rgb(.5,.5,.5),
                    rgb(.8,.55,0),
                    rgb(.8,0,0)),
     vertex.size = 20,
     layout = coords,
     main = paste("Graph", toString(1)))
```

and produced the following

[image]

I would like the 1->2 edge to be deleted but the 2 ->3 edge to remain. Any ideas on what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `delete_edges` function assumes you are passing in an edge index. You can see the edges with

```
E(g1)
# + 5/5 edges from faf79f6:
# [1] 1->2 2->3 3->4 4->5 5->1
```

so when you specify `c(1,2)` you are specifying the first and second edges, not the edge that goes form vertex 1 to 2. If you wanted to do that instead, you could do

```
g1 <- delete_edges(g1, E(g1)[1 %--% 2])
```

Another way to do this is

```
g1 <- g1 - edge("1|2")
```

If you do have a vertex sqeuence that you would like to extract the edges for, you can use the `P=` parameter of the E()` function. For example

```
g1 <- delete_edges(g1, E(g1, P=c(1,2,3,4)))
```

This will remove the edge that goes from 1 to 2, and 3 to 4.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer when it allows me to. Is this also true of add_edges?

Comment: Nope. According to the documentation for `add_edges` you pass a "a vertex sequence with even number of vertices". So `add_edges` expected a vertex sequence while `delete_edges` expects an edge sequence.

Comment: Also, what if I would like to delete a list of edges. For instance, if I wanted to delete the edge 1 -> 2 and 3 -> 4. I thought you would write it like g1 <- delete_edges(g1,c(1,2,3,4)). Is there a way to achieve something like that?

Comment: @jd123 I updated with a possible alternative for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete_edges(g, get.edge.ids(g, c(1,2)))
```

will delete an edge incident with vertex 1 and 2.